# Deploying StrongLoop App in AWS server

Tags: javascript, strongloop, loopbackjs

I have built a strong loop app and I want to deploy in aws server. Please note that I have not purchased the Strongloop AMI but i am using a regular aws instance. My source code is in svn. When I went through the documention for deploying in aws, what is the process? Is GIT is mandatory or can anyone share me the steps

Comment: When I use the slc run -d command, the server is running. But when there is any error (for e.g. while executing a REST command) , then the server shuts down. That should not be the case rite. I believe even if there is any run time error, the server needs to be up and running. please advice.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using the StrongLoop AMI, you would go through the same installation steps that you would for any other machine. Note you will need to start with getting Node installed and then the StrongLoop module from npm. See link below.

Git is required for some StrongLoop modules like the process manager.

http://docs.strongloop.com/display/SLC/Getting+started+with+StrongLoop+Controller

Comment: I am able to run the Process manager. But when i deploy using "slc deploy http://localhost:7777/repo", i get the following error "This directory does not contain a valid git repository". Please note that i am using AWS and my source code is hosted in svn. Does this mean that if we want to deploy, the source code needs to be hosted in git?

Answer (score 0):

It's 
slc deploy [options] URL [ package | branch ]

The URL is to your pm, like this

```
http://localhost:7777/repo
```

the package can be a tgz file too if it is local. http://docs.strongloop.com/display/SLC/slc+deploy

Comment: Hi I am using the following command in aws slc deploy http://localhost:7777 mytarfile-0.0.0.tgz and the strong loop process manager is running in 7777. But i get the following error message Deploy `/opt/mytarfile-0.0.0.tgz` to `http://127.0.0.1:7777` failed. HTTP Code: 405

Comment: please run slc -v and check to make sure that strong-pm is at least v 0.1.9, the latest version is   
strong-pm@1.2.0 . If not please run "slc update" to get the latest  version.